# Memory usage an parallel programming

Tags: c++, memory, parallel-processing

I do not know much about parallel computing but I want to make a suggestion for "Further Work" on an assignment and want to make sure I am right. 
I have written a ray tracer in C++. I store information of the rays, such as hitpoints, in  `vector` and I write these vectors to CSV at the end of the simulation (is that good programming?)  If I trace a number of rays say 1000 the simulation takes more time compared to tracing 100 rays 10 times. I assume this is because my the size of my `vector's` are larger and so they take up a lot of space in heap memory(?). Each ray can be traced without information from the other rays (the program is begging to be made parallel). Am I correct is saying that if the program were parallel each processor will have its own memory and so there wont be one large vector taking a huge block of memory but rather small vectors spread around which can be handled more efficiently?

Comment: Or perhaps make the program threaded (`std::thread`) to allow parallel execution.

Comment: Quite likely that you're using different rays in your 1x1000 vs 10x100 test. If so, I'd investigate that the same rays are having their times measured. I'd be willing to bet a not-so-small body-part that the size of the vectors is entirely irrelevant. Main memory speed is measured in GB/s - A 'couple' (of thousand or million) extra elements is going to have no discernible effect on execution speed. Why dont you write some profiling code to look at the speed of vectors (or find someone else's result) QueryHighPerformanceFrequency and QueryHighPerformanceTimer - both handy if working on windows.

Comment: Ok - that basically answers my question. A vector of a couple of million elements won't substantially effect the simulation compared to a smaller vector. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption about each processor having its own 'memory' sounds like an attempt to improve CPU cache usage (RAM remains the same regardless of how parallel your task is - unless you are distributing it on a cluster). While in general parallelizing gives more CPU cache, there can be even more cache misses as threads will migrate between cores (Windows actually does this).

Maybe you are just using std::vector in a inefficient way. E.g. you are inserting items at the beginning or appending items one by one (these operations could take up to O(`vector.size()`)). Or there may be other data structure which slows down when number of rays increases. And this probably can be fixed without splitting the task between several processors.

Although the program will definitely gain from parallelizing.

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing. I was never required to 'process' my results so I took a lot of effort in efficiently tracing the ray through the scene. But to show what I'm doing is actually correct, every time a ray hits an object I append a `vector` with the coordinates of that hitpoint and continue with the calculation. At the end, I write that vector to csv and use Matlab to plot pretty pictures - is there a quick-fix-smater way of doing this?

Comment: What is the final number of elements in the vector? You can set vector's capacity to this number (or a bit greater) to avoid memory reallocations when appending new elements: `your_vector.reserve(1000000);` (given that you will store maximum 1000000 items)
The more intelligent way could be to have a reasonably-sized buffer for this output data and flush it to CSV file eventually rather than store everything in RAM and make one big write at the end.

Comment: I considered sizing the vector but unfortunately a ray can bounce all around the scene and so number of hitpoints will be far greater than number of objects. For the buffer, am I understanding you: I have a `vector.reserve(100000k)` and I routinely write it to CSV as it reaches capacity?

Comment: Definitely. But I think you already know amount of hitpoints for your 1000-ray test, so it's easy to try and see whether the problem is in vector or elsewhere. And then you can implement more intelligent schemes (if you don't like writing the results to file eventually, you can just make the vector to grow by large chunks: instead of `v.append()` write something like `if (v.capacity() == v.size()) { v.reserve(v.capacity() + (1<<20)); } v.append(...);` thus making the vector to grow by 2^20 items at once.